# Netlify Not Rendering React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, hosting, netlify

Here is the link to my React project https://github.com/Count-T/blogfrontend, I ran npm run build and put that folder into netlify but when I check the app it only shows a blank page. I don't know is the problem is react-router but I already put a file to redirect netlify to index.html. This is my second time uploading a project onto netlify but my previous project did not use react-router-dom. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Link to netlify website: https://tonyliblog.netlify.app/
Here is an image of the website [image]

Answer (score 0):

I do see an error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" in the console on the netlify site. I don't know if that could help you to pin down the issue. Did it run without any problem in your local env? Are you using any environment variables/ Keys to access your API?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the router. I have looked at your code and it seems ok to me. Probably you may need to do the trial and error with the individual components and see which one has the problem.

Comment: Yes it runs on my localhost and this project has no dotenv file only in a separate backend folder project where this project connects do with axios. My backend is hosted on heroku.

Comment: Yo lets go! I deployed the frontend to heroku and it worked I dont know why it didnt work on netlify tho, but thanks for your help anyways.